# CFT - cloud foundation toolkit error

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have been having a problem running CFT on Google Cloud shell or any other linux server. After installing all the pre-requisites upon running cft, I get the same error everywhere:

```
Steps
cloned Cloud foundation toolkit fro Github

cd dm
sudo make cft-prerequisites   
make build                    
sudo make install 

XXXXXXX:~/cloud-foundation-toolkit/dm$ cft
/usr/bin/python: No module named cloud_foundation_toolkit
XXXXX~/cloud-foundation-toolkit/dm$
```

Answer (score 0):

After following your same steps I've managed to reproduce your issue.

In order to solve it I've followed the [CFT Developer Guide](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-foundation-toolkit/blob/master/dm/docs/tool_dev_guide.md#cft-developer-guide) and I got the `cft` command working.

The steps differ in that the guide creates and uses a virtual environment to execute the command. The steps are:

```
sudo make cft-prerequisites
make cft-venv
source venv/bin/activate
source src/cftenv
```

Please read the [documentation](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-foundation-toolkit/blob/master/dm/docs/tool_dev_guide.md#development-environment) in order to know the details of each command and how to exit the environment.